Holomorphic function invariant under real translations
Suppose $F(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ is holomorphic in $n$ complex variables. For simplicity, assume the domain is all of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Suppose further that for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$, we have the identity \begin{equation}F(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=F(z_1-a,\ldots,z_n-a)\end{equation} Is it true that $F$ only depends on the relative differences $z_i-z_{i+1}$? In other words, does there exists some other holomorphic function $G(z_1,\ldots,z_{n-1})$ of $n-1$ variables such that \begin{equation}F(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=G(z_1-z_2,\ldots,z_n-z_{n-1})\end{equation}
If we allow $a$ to be any complex number, then this is somewhat obvious since, if $n=2$ for example, we can define $G(z):=F(z,0)$ so that $G(z_1-z_2)=F(z_1-z_2,0)=F(z_1-z_2+z_2,z_2)=F(z_1,z_2)$. But I am having trouble using this same argument for $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Also, does anything change if we restrict the domain of $F$ to a proper subset $U\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ (so long as real translation still makes sense)?

for the first part if you fix $(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ and consider $g_{(z_1,\ldots,z_n)}(a)=F(z_1-a,\ldots,z_n-a)-F(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ that is entire analytic and zero on the reals so is zero everywhere hence the relation holds for every complex $a$ and your reasoning applies; for the second part not sure what it means anymore $\begin{equation}F(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=G(z_1-z_2,\ldots,z_n-z_{n-1})\end{equation}$ since you need the domains to work out
